# Can I use Google Apps Script to make a Google Form display randomized text from a Google Sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

Say I have a list of 1000 animals in a Google Sheet (e.g., dog, cat, cow, ..., giraffe).  I'll like the Google Form to randomly pick one of these animals every time a respondent opens the Form.

E.g., Have you ever seen a __________ ?

Here, the blank would be different for every respondent (unless they were lucky enough to randomly get matching animals).

I currently have the code to randomly select an animal from the Google Sheet, but I can't figure out how to randomly select an animal for each respondent, since the onOpen() function cannot trigger for every respondent, but only when the owner opens the Form.

```
function onOpen(e){
  var animals = worksheet.getRange(2, 1, worksheet.getLastRow()-1, 1)
              .getValues()
              .map(function(o){ return o[0]})
              .filter(function(o){return o !== ""});
  //Logger.log(animals)

  // get random animal
  var animal = animals[Math.floor(Math.random()*animals.length)];

  Logger.log(animal);
  var id = getBlockIdFromTitle()
  Logger.log(id) 

  if (id !== -1){
    updateLink(id, animal)
  }
}
```

Any advice on how to change my code or do a completely different approach to achieve the same results will be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Please fix code blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Instead of `onOpen` trigger, use the [installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#g_suite_application_triggers) `onFormSubmit` trigger

This will allow you to update your form question after a respondent has submitted the form.

Sample:

```
function onFormSubmit(e){
  var animals = worksheet.getRange(2, 1, worksheet.getLastRow()-1, 1)
              .getValues()
              .map(function(o){ return o[0]})
              .filter(function(o){return o !== ""});
  //Logger.log(animals)

  // get random animal
  var animal = animals[Math.floor(Math.random()*animals.length)];
  FormApp.openById("XXX").getItems()[0].asTextItem().setTitle("Have you ever seen a " + animal + "?");
  }
}
```

**Mind:**

- Since the question will only be updated on form submit, the respondents that will open the form before the preceding respondent finishes submitting will not see a different version of the form.
- However, currently there is no other option to change the question contents dynamically for each respondent.
- If it is helpful for your - there options to [shuffle](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308764?hl=en) question order and answer options to different respondents.