# Randomize google forms sections with Gsuit?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms, page-break

I need to randomize the SECTIONS (not questions) in my google form. The reason I need to do sections is because every section corresponds to a video so each needs to be a section.

This is the closest thing I've gotten to a solution:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/page-break-item

```
// Create a form and add three page-break items.
var form = FormApp.create('Form Name');
var pageTwo = form.addPageBreakItem().setTitle('Page Two');
var pageThree = form.addPageBreakItem().setTitle('Page Three');

// Make the first two pages navigate elsewhere upon completion.
pageTwo.setGoToPage(pageThree); // At end of page one (start of page two), jump to page three
pageThree.setGoToPage(FormApp.PageNavigationType.RESTART); // At end of page two, restart form
```

I've already made the form and don't want to remake it (so many questions, so many videos). If I could use the .setGoToPage function shown above I think I could find a solution to randomize the sections aka pages. I just don't know what the names of my already existing pages are or how to find them. Please help!!!!

Answer (score 1):

### As you noticed yourself the methods applicable to a page are very limited

- So, while you can add a page break, you cannot retrieve it in a subsequent code execution, and thus there is no way to shuffle it.
- There is also no way to retrieve or set the questions belonging to each page in order to create new pages with questions on each script execution.
- You have the possibility to file relevant feature requests on Google's [Public Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker), chances are they will be implemented in the future if enough users show interest
- In the mean time, as a workaround the only 2 things I can come up with is

  - a) Duplicate your form, shuffle the pages manually from the UI for each duplicate, create a [WebApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) that will arbitrary redirect the user to one of the URLs of the different form versions
  - b) Summarize all questions belonging to one page / section into one question item - it is easy to [shuffle](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#setshufflequestionsshuffle) opposed to pages

In case it's helpful - further information:

- [How to shuffle questions each time a form is submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60927893/11599789)
- [How to shuffle questions on time-driven trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60115867/11599789)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I ended up using qualtrics - too many hoops to jump through. Hopefully one day google forms will become more dev friendly!